# Azure Machine Learning - Predicting a win/lose/draw API

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm experimenting with an existing experiment on the Azure Machine learning gallery.  Its called [beat the bookie](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Beat-the-Bookie).  I want to take it to the next step and add a web service to it.  This particular experiment has a dataset for years of matches.  It has a small python script to calculate an ELO (like chess or most online games).  I'm struggling to create an input API with 2 inputs: homeTeam and awayTeam.  With an output of 1 value FTR (Full-Time Result) which is either W/D/L (Win, Draw or Lose).

The issue I have is that when I create the API it has too many required inputs.  Do I have to give them averaged data or how do I reduce the inputs to 2?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to reduce it to just two inputs since the algorithm needs all inputs in order to make a prediction. You *may* be able to pass in average values for the rest, though, but I wouldn't think it would give a good prediction.

Comment: Thanks @Jon it does seem impossible.  It would be nice if the inputs were optional.
I'm not great at Python, but it would be nice if python got the averages but does this still leave us with all the inputs?

Comment: Possibly. If using a pandas data frame you could just get the mean value for each column. The categorical columns would be tricky, though. You could use the most common of the categories.